# How do I sort my data?

Tags: c, loops

I am new to programming so this is difficult for me. I need the program to end if the user's first input is -999, if not then they go on to input the account_num, last_name, and balance. But if the user enters -999 after the first input then it ends their input and displays the results. I cannot figure out how to get this whole -999 part to work while making my client[x].account_num be sorted in ascending order.. My code is below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void bubble_sort(int[], int);

struct information
{
    int     account_num;
    char    last_name[30];
    float   balance;
};

int main()
{
    /* declare variables */
    struct information   client[5];
    int       i, x, temp; 
    char      c;

    /* Prompt user */
    printf ("Enter account number, last name, and balance.\n");
    printf ("Enter -999 to end input:\n\n");

    /* prompt user to enter number of people */
    x = 0;
    while (client[x].account_num != -999)
    {
    int tmp;
        scanf ("%i", &tmp);
        /* if types -999 as their first input program ends */
        if (tmp == -999)    
        {
            break;
        }
        else if (tmp < 1 || tmp > 1000) 
        {
            printf ("*** Invalid account number. Please enter 1 - 1000 or -999 to exit ***\n");
        }
        else
        {
        client[x].account_num = tmp;
            x ++;
        }
        bubble_sort(client[x].account_num, i);
        scanf("%s", client[x].last_name);
        while ( (c = getchar() != '\n') && c != EOF); /* clear input buffer. */
        scanf("%.2f", &client[x].balance);
    }

    for (x = 0; x < 5; x++)
    printf("%i\n", &client[x].account_num);

  return 0;
}    

void bubble_sort(int list[], int i)
{
    int e, d, t;

    for (e = 0; e < (i - 1); e++)
    {
        for (d = 0; d < i - e - 1; d++)
        {
            if (list[d] > list[d + 1])
            {
               /* swapping */
               t = list[d];
               list[d] = list[d + 1];
               list[d + 1] = t;
           }/* end for*/
       }/*end for*/
    }/* end for */
}/* end function */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues here. First, you don't want to index `account_num` and `balance` in the struct, unless you want to have several account numbers and balances per account holder. I also suggest replacing the `for` with a `while` loop so you don't have to fiddle with the loop counter `x` in case the user enters an invalid account number. Finally, for the sake of clarity I introduced a temporary variable `tmp`for input and performed all tests on it, assigning the content to the account structure only if all validity tests were passed. `tmp`is only needed inside the `while`loop which is why I declared it there, instead of making it part of the declarations in `main()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_CLIENTS  5
#define MAX_ACCOUNTS 1000

struct information
{
    int     account_num;
    char    last_name[30];
    float   balance;
};

int main()
{
    /* declare variables */
    struct information   client[MAX_CLIENTS];
    int       i, x, people; 
    char      c;

    /* Prompt user */
    printf ("Enter account number, last name, and balance.\n");
    printf ("Enter -999 to end input:\n\n");

    /* prompt user to enter number of people */
    x = 0;
    while (x < MAX_CLIENTS)
    {
        int tmp;
        scanf ("%i", &tmp);

        /* if types -999 as their first input program ends */
        if (tmp == -999)    
        {
            break;
        }
        else if (tmp < 1 || tmp > MAX_ACCOUNTS) 
        {
            printf ("*** Invalid account number. Please enter 1 - %d or   -999 to exit ***\n", MAX_ACCOUNTS);
        }
        else
        {
            client[x].account_num = tmp;
            x ++;
        }
    }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I have been trying to figure out how I would go about doing this. Every time I tried it would just put out the "Invalid" line.

Comment: But how would I get it so that the loop doesn't just end after 5 lines? How can I get it to end only if -999 is input

Comment: @user5932832 You defined `client[5]` which holds 5 clients, therefore the loop must end after 5 entries. Otherwise your client array would run out of bounds. I parametrized the code a bit more, adding a MAX_CLIENTS definition at the top so you only need to change the max. number of clients in one place. In the end, it all depends on what you want to achieve – whether you want the user to specify the number of clients, whether you want to allow multiple re-edits of details for the same client etc. Your example currently leaves it a bit unclear in which direction the functionality should go.

Comment: I changed my loop to continue as long as it is != -999. But how would I go about sorting my client[x].account_num in ascending order? I tried to sort it, but when I do, the whole -999 portion does not work. I updated my code above

Comment: @user5932832 You'll need to move the bubble_sort call outside the loop: `bubble_sort(…); for (x = …) printf (…) ;` since it's necessary to sort the array only after all client data has been entered. Also, your current version of bubble_sort probably won't work: it's coded to sort a simple array, but you're giving it an array with structured members.